# react-native-maps animateToRegion has lower deltas (smaller region) than onRegionChangeComplete

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react native maps in typescript in an iOS app. My initial region is pretty small, with latitudeDelta = 0.0000922 and longitudeDelta=0.0000922*(screenwidth/screenheight). My code uses useRef to save a reference to the MapView and when I get the first location (first latitude and longitude) from my server, I use mapRef.current.animateToRegion to animate to the region:

```
const INITIAL_LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0000922;
const INITIAL_LONGITUDE_DELTA = INITIAL_LATITUDE_DELTA*(screenwidth/screenheight);

const server_callback = (serverResult) => {
    ...
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
        latitude: serverResult.latitude,
        longitude: serverResult.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: INITIAL_LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: INITIAL_LONGITUDE_DELTA
    });
}
```

This works fine and shows my little region (about the size of a suburban backyard, a little blurry but fine). But I also want to allow the user to zoom in and out using hand gestures (pinch and expand) so I implement onRegionChangeComplete:

```
  const onRegionChangeComplete = (newRegion: Region) => {
      setRegion(newRegion);
  }
```

The problem is that as soon as I do this, the size of the region expands to (what appears to be) the minimum size allowed by setRegion for the map. It seems like as soon as the user uses a gesture to change the region, or even uses a swipe to move it, the region size (the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta) suddenly increase in value so that what I get in the region newRegion inside onRegionChangeComplete is this larger region. I can't zoom in any closer than this.

My MapView is defined like this:

```
<MapView mapType="satellite" style={styles.map} initialRegion={region} onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete} ref={mapRef}>
....
</MapView>
```

So, is it the case that animateToRegion allows me to zoom more than manual region changes allow? I need one of two things. Either I need to find a way to allow the manual gestures to keep this high zoom level (low deltas), or I need to know what the minimum values for the deltas are so that I can uses these as my initial/default values. How would I do either of these?